# String will not convert to uppercase when placed as argument value

Tags: javascript, toupper

I am trying to place a dynamic argument value in a onclick function. The problem is that it seems to convert it to lowercase as well as adds an extra space in front of it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is a codepen.io of my code: http://codepen.io/theller5567/pen/GZwBrE?editors=1010

Here is my function:

```
createList: function(scope){
      var country = scope;
      var cc = country.countryCode;
      var ccc = cc.toUpperCase();
      console.log(ccc);
      if(ccc){
         var listItem = '<li><a href="#" onclick="setCountry("'+ccc+'","'+country.country+'");getDistribution(event);">'+country.country+'</a></li>';
         return listItem;
      }
 },
```

Here is an example of what one of the listitem looks like in the dom:

```
<a href="#" onclick="setCountry(" il","israel");getdistribution(event);">Israel</a>
```

the console log will show all the country codes in full uppercase but the codes in the dom show as lowercase as well as an extra space in front of it.

Comment: My only thought is that the way i have my quotes is messing with it. But i do not know any other way to get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my concatenation quotes wrong.

```
createList: function(scope){
      var country = scope;
    var cc = country.countryCode;
    var ccc = cc.toUpperCase();
    console.log(ccc);
    if(ccc){
      var listItem = '<li><a href="#" onclick="setCountry('+ccc+','+country.country+');getDistribution(event);">'+country.country+'</a></li>';
      return listItem;
    }
    },
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion nearly one hour after I saw your problem only to find you had already solved it :( anyway. Good thing that you solved it. :)

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Thank you for taking the time to help.